# How to have an I-Beam bend as little as possible

Tags: structural-beam

I have an I-Beam cantilever beam and apply a force to the free end. If I want the displacement in the vertical axis of the end being forced to be as small as possible from that when no force is present will I want the web or flange to be bigger?

I have since done a few beam tests and these are my results: [image]

[image]

These would make it appear that in fact a larger flange means that there is more displacement don't they?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the stress you need to support because of *buckling* as is visible in your first diagram. This also means it depends on how the force is applied - at a point, at the top, across the end?

For small forces (no worries about buckling) you want the tallest thinnest beam since you are maximizing the second moment of area for constant area. However in the limit that will always buckle so now you have to make it thicker (in the middle) and shorter - with any spare material relegated to the edges.

I don't think there is a single right answer; it really does depend on the max stress you must be able to sustain.

Comment: It's hard (or impossible) to say exactly that the buckling is real in that first image. We don't know anything about the numerical model, mesh, etc to judge whether it's a physical process or a numerical artifact.

Comment: @tpg2114 - that's true, but absent worries about buckling the tallest thinnest structure will have the highest second moment of area; you back off from that design until you do not exceed the buckling strength. Without constraints the solution diverges to an infinitely thin and tall sheet.

Comment: Hi Floris, Are you saying that buckling is a more important consideration than static displacement? I've done a variety of tests and the've given different results. Should I focus on the ones where buckling is the least over other factors? I have found that it will normally always occur at a very low force. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want the 2 flanges at either side to be bigger.  The reason the I-Beam cross-section is shaped that way is because it is the material furthest from the centroid (i.e. the 2 flanges) that is providing the most stiffness against bending. The material closer to the centroid is not providing as much stiffness, so it makes sense to take most of that away to reduce the weight (and improve the stiffness:weight ratio).

[Bending stiffness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending) is related to the second moment of area of the cross-section, which for an I-Beam is larger in the direction of bending that is aligned with the central web. If you look at any structural application where I-Beams are used, they are always oriented that way.

Comment: Hi Time4Tea, thats what I thought but could you please look at the pictures I've uploaded, they seem to indicate that a bigger web means less displacement. Surely that can't be correct?

Comment: The stiffness is proportional to the second moment of area, so a bigger web will give you less displacement. **But**, if you add that same amount of cross-sectional area to the outer flanges instead, it should give you a _bigger_ increase in stiffness, so the bending should be even less.

Comment: Oh, you mean increasing the _length_ of the web or flanges? In that case I'm not so sure, as increasing the length of the web will move the flanges further apart, which will increase the second moment of area. Tbh, I think you would have to calculate the second moment of area in each case and see what you get. Btw, I don't think you really need to use FEA for this - it should be fairly straightforward to use hand calcs.

Comment: Also, why are you simulating it as 2 c-sections joined together? It looks like that might be affecting your results ...

Comment: I'm tasked with making a strong beam out of sheet metal, so I though two c shapes would be best to make an I.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't realized this was in sheet metal, but now I see the images that is clear. So, do you have a fixed width of the sheet and are wondering whether to put that into the web or the end flanges? I agree with Floris' answer that in this case buckling will be a major factor, as the sheet is so thin, and it will be more complex so hand calcs might be difficult.

Comment: I would definitely check how accurate the bucking model is in your FEA program, as that will be a big factor in how accurate the solution is. Some of the cheap ones may not model it very well beyond just Euler buckling. Also, how you set up the model/mesh/simulation will be very important, as the problem will be more non-linear.